# Calculate X and Y based on element width and height

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to convert the current `width` and `height` of the element to `x, y` position.

`this.minWidth` - it's a minimal width of the component, it can be like const 60,
`this.minHeight` - same as above, it is a const.

In `initDrag(e)` I am initializing both start `width` and `height` values.

```
const element = document.querySelector(`.id-${this.data.id}`);

this.startWidth = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element).width, 10);
this.startHeight = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element).height, 10);
```

In `onDrag(event)` I am setting current `width` and `height` of the element and after those settings would like to convert them into `x` and `y` position. Based on `css grid` system.

```
const width = this.startWidth + event.clientX - this.startX;
const height = this.startHeight + event.clientY - this.startY;
```

I have written two methods which recalculate them but seems like they are not working well.

```
getColumnBasedOnWidth(width) {
    const spacingBetweenColumns = 21;
    const numberOfColumnSpacings = (Math.floor(width / this.minWidth) - 1);
    return Math.floor((width - numberOfColumnSpacings * spacingBetweenColumns) / this.minWidth);
},
getRowBasedOnHeight(height) {
    const spacingBetweenRows = 41;
    const numberOfRowSpacings = (Math.floor(height / this.minHeight) - 1);
    return Math.floor((height - numberOfRowSpacings * spacingBetweenRows) / this.minHeight);
},
```

Between each column is a gap equal `21`, between each row is a gap equal `41`.

The layout css layout look like:

```
    // Default layout schema:
    //                           COLUMNS
    //    1         2   2         3   3         4   4         5
    //
    //   1 ----------------------------------------------------
    //    |                                                    |
    //    |                      SECTION                       |
    //   2 ----------------------------------------------------
    //
    // R 2 ----------    ----------    ----------    ----------
    // O  |    X     |  |          |  |          |  |          |
    // w  |   ITEM   |  |   ITEM   |  |   ITEM   |  |   ITEM   |
    //   3 ----------    ----------    ----------    ----------
    //
    //   3 ----------------------------------------------------
    //    |                                                    |
    //    |                      SECTION                       |
    //   4 ----------------------------------------------------
    // And so on
```

We can start resizing element on drag in right bottom corner. As an example, we can drag the first element marked as `X` and tracking his position converted to `x`, `y`.